# Is it possible for Superman to have sex in a red sun chamber?

Tags: dc, superman

It is quite obvious that if Superman had sex with a normal human, he would kill them. Therefore, I think the only way possible for him to have sex is in a red sun room. Has it ever been shown or mentioned in the comics?

Comment: The dupe specifically mentions instances where Superman has had sex with Lois without being in a red sun chamber.

Comment: I don't know why the question was closed as duplicate. I did not find anything in the other question that answers my question. It is absolutely not possible for Superman to have sex with Lois without a red sun chamber or completely removing his powers. If there are some other ways, I would definitely like to know.

Comment: @Valorum Please read my last comment. Also, the dupe only mentions "some" of the instances where they had sex, not how.

Comment: It quite clearly _is_ possible for Superman to be intimate with a human and not hurt them because _it has happened_. So your premise is flawed.

Comment: @KutuluMike Did you not read my last comment? I said it has happened but I want to know "how" it happened. Nevermind, it seems the only thing this site is good at is looking down on newbies. So far, I am yet to find a single satisfying answer to any of my questions. I'm out of here.

Comment: Your question specifically says "t is quite obvious that if Superman had sex with a normal human, he would kill them". That is in incorrect statement, so it's impossible to answer the question the way you want. If you want to know _how_ Superman has sex with Lois, the question we linked you to is everything we know about it, so if the answer's not in there than we don't have an answer.